# Is this newspaper clipping about Dave Prowse revealing a major Star Wars plot twist two years in advance, genuine?

Tags: movies

Arguably the most famous scene in *Star Wars* is when Darth Vader reveals to Luke Skywalker that

> He is Luke's father.

According to most sources, this surprise was kept secret to most of the crew and even the cast [during production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Empire_Strikes_Back#Production), with Dave Prowse, the actor playing Darth Vader, delivering a fake line, the actual line being overdubbed. (Of course, Darth Vader wasn't voiced by him in the first place; all lines were overdubbed by James Earl Jones).

Like Mark Hamill relates in [an interview](https://www.soundandvision.com/news/100104hamill/):

> **But, for example, your big scene, one of the classic cinematic moments when Darth Vader divulges his true identity, is no longer a revelation.**
>
> It's such a great moment! The fake line that was put in there just to try and keep the secret was "You don't know the truth: Obi-Wan killed your father!" But as much as I enjoyed leaking false information, it was a wonderfully hard secret to keep because (Irvin) Kershner, the director, brought me aside and said "Now I know this, and George knows this, and now you're going to know this, but if you tell anybody, and that means Carrie or Harrison, or anybody, we're going to know who it is because we know who knows."

But recently, a newspaper clipping [surfaced](https://www.retroist.com/2010/11/08/1978-style-star-wars-spoilers/), in which we read about Dave Prowse revealing this same surprise twist to about a thousand fans, two years before the release of *The Empire Strikes Back*.

[image: A newspaper clipping in which Dave Prowse reveals the surprise to about a thousand fans]

I have asked [a question about this on another stack](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/66661/19561), where somebody suggested it might possibly be fake. So that's my question here: is it real?

Comment: Some stuff doesn't add up.  Hamill claims to be the only cast member told - and was apparently told during filming...  But Prowse knew *before* filming even started?  Also in that clipping, Prowse talks about Star Wars II, III and *IV*....  Hmmmm.

Comment: +1 just for including the necessary(?) spoiler cover.

Comment: This question is answered in much greater detail in the SciFi version of the question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66661/exactly-how-secret-was-the-reveal-in-the-empire-strikes-back.

Comment: Note that this doesn't mean Prowse actually knew. It could be a fun speculation — and besides, it's not a massive leap to go from Obi-Wan's hesitant comments to this conclusion. Heck, for all we know, Lucas could have gotten the idea from this interview ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a real clipping from the [San Francisco Examiner, July 24, 1978](https://sfexaminer.newspapers.com/browse/the-san-francisco-examiner_9317/1978/07/24/), page 4:

[image: clipping at top left]

(I don’t have a subscription for this, so I can’t get a better picture. Article located thanks to a reference to the title in [How Star Wars Conquered the Universe](https://www.google.com/books/edition/How_Star_Wars_Conquered_the_Universe/uG0uCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22may%20the%20sequel%20be%20with%20you%22%20%22star%20wars%22&pg=PT315&printsec=frontcover).)

Comment: Have you been able to read the text of the article (or at least the last paragraph) and confirm that the text matches?  It's not legible in this image.

Comment: @NateEldredge It’s not 100% legible in any image I have access to, but the following is clear enough to show that the text seems to be an exact match: https://img.newspapers.com/img/thumbnail/460822316/400.jpg

Comment: (Edited the above into post)

Answer (score 15):

It **probably** isn't fake, because I was able to find a completely different independent  article quoting David Prowse, from the same event, with **100% identical money quote: "son can't kill father, father can't kill son"**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGIBR.jpg

[image]

In addition, most forums/posts discussing the topics are full of comments from people stating they saw the original article.

While it's possible someone photoshopped this second image, the likelyhood is that the quote is accurate

Comment: I wish I could go with NO for this one. It just doesn't make any sense. Take it from http://youtu.be/rWRfQaNinF0?t=2m38s 1980s interview of David Prowse himself where he is telling everyone "It surprised me actually, cause I didn't know anything about it, until I was sat in the cinema last Saturday. And that was the first I knew of it"

Comment: @dmin doesnt have to contradict. He was likely randomly guessing In an earlier interview

Comment: Still it doesn't add up. You don't randomly guess it, and use same quote again and again (I assume articles are made  at different times), you are either convinced that it is true, or you know it is not and use it to mislead people for whatever reason. Either way there is no way of finding this out, unless going to newspaper archives.

Comment: @DMINATOR - it's not such a completely implausible idea that it's impossible to guess. And the articles are different yet the quote seems from the same exact event.

Comment: What is the actual reference here? What magazine can I look this up in?

Comment: @Oddthinking - There were 2 different articles scanned, both posted on reddit and neither had magazine name in the post sorry :(  I doubt they are photoshopped, but have no way to prove they weren't other than "why would anyone care" logical fallacy :).

Comment: I know it is way too late (and I apologise) but linking to the Reddit posts would have been the best bet.

Comment: It's not like we weren't reading "Dark Father" into the words "Darth Vader" in 1977.

Comment: @Oddthinking - seems rather useless, but here you go: https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/2egkma/david_prowse_spoiled_empire_strikes_back_two/, https://retroist.com/1978-style-star-wars-spoilers/, https://www.cinelinx.com/off-beat/old-newspaper-clipping-prooves-vader-spoiled-the-ending-to-empire-2-years-before-it-released/